# Python memory issue uploading multiple files to API

Tags: python

I'm running a script to upload 20k+ XML files to an API. About 18k in, I get a memory error. I was looking into it and found the memory is just continually climbing until it reaches the limit and errors out (seemingly on the post call). Anyone know why this is happening or a fix? Thanks. I have tried the streaming uploads found [here](https://2.python-requests.org//en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads). The empty strings are due to sensitive data.

```
def upload(self, oauth_token, full_file_path):
        file_name = os.path.basename(full_file_path)
        upload_endpoint = {'':''}
        params = {'': '','': ''}
        headers = {'': '', '': ''}
        handler = None
        try:
            handler = open(full_file_path, 'rb')
            response = requests.post(url=upload_endpoint[''], params=params, data=handler, headers=headers, auth=oauth_token, verify=False, allow_redirects=False, timeout=600)
            status_code = response.status_code
            # status checking
            return status_code
        finally:
            if handler:
                handler.close()

    def push_data(self):
        oauth_token = self.get_oauth_token()
        files = os.listdir(f_dir)
        for file in files:
            status = self.upload(oauth_token, file_to_upload)
```

Comment: I don't know if it's related to the issue, but use context managers to handle files. What is the try doing here? Why is there a `self` parameters, are these part of a class?

Comment: @AMC there is error handling in the status checking area that uses it. I just removed it to shorten the code block. Yes this is part of a class.

Comment: What is the class for? Have you benchmarked/profiled the code?

Comment: @AMC Just to upload these files. It was passed along to me by another dev team. Profiling it is a little difficult because of where the computer resides. It is remote.

Comment: _Just to upload these files._ I hope it's a good use case for a class. _Profiling it is a little difficult because of where the computer resides. It is remote._ Unfortunate, I guess. Can you run it with the change I suggested on a smaller input, and see if it behaves differently?

Comment: @AMC I'm unfamiliar with context managers, but I have tried using "with open(full_file_path, 'rb') as handler:" and that didnt work. Idk if that is what you are referring to or not. I dont have a lot of python experience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206103/discussion-between-amc-and-c10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Python are you using? It looks like there is a bug in Python 3.4 causing memory leaks related to network requests. See here for a similar issue: https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/5215

It may help to update Python.

Comment: Looks like that was the issue. Thanks!